# Как сделать Sleep в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Через 2 секунды после первого рисунка должен появиться второй. Как сделать приостановку программы? Много чего перепробовал. Либо программа виснет, либо просто не работает.

```
void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 1, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::FlatCap));

    if(ui->startButton->isChecked()){
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::red, Qt::SolidPattern));
        painter.drawRect(20,30, 180, 120);
        // здесь должна быть пауза
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::green, Qt::SolidPattern));
        painter.drawEllipse(100, 150, 180, 200);
    } 
    else if(ui->pauseButton->isChecked()){
    } 
    else if(ui->cleanButton->isChecked()){
    }
}

void Widget::on_startButton_clicked()
{
    repaint();
}

void Widget::on_pauseButton_clicked()
{
    repaint();
}

void Widget::on_cleanButton_clicked()
{
    repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Заснуть можно в трех вариантах с помощью статических функций `QThread`:

```
void QThread::msleep(unsigned long msecs);
void QThread::sleep (unsigned long  secs);
void QThread::usleep(unsigned long usecs);
```

Но только в вашем случае это не лучшая идея. Потому что отрисовка производится в главном потоке приложения и пока он спит, обработка событий, сообщений и пр. в этом потоке выполняться не будет. То есть фактически все приложение будет стоять 3 секунды, а это многовато.

Для вашей задачи лучше подойдут таймеры. В Qt есть очень удобный [QTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html). Второй вариант, если ван нужно постояно через определенные промежутки что-либо выполнять, то можно использовать "встроенные" в `QObject` таймеры. Создаются/удаляются эти таймеры с помощью функций [startTimer/killTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#startTimer), обрабатываются в виртуальной функции `QObject::timerEvent`.

А чтобы не зависало для перерисовки используйте `update()` вместо `repaint()`.

Answer (score 5):

Если у вас Qt5, то можно так:

```
QThread::sleep(2);
```

В Qt4 этот метод защищенный, поэтому придется малость извернуться:

```
void sleep(int ms){
   static QMutex mutex;
   static QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
   mutex.tryLock(ms);
}

//...

sleep(2000);
```

Но имейте ввиду эти функции приостанавливают поток. Если вы вызовите их в главном потоке, программа зависнет на 2 секунды.

Чтобы сделать что-то через определенный промежуток времени и при этом не приостанавливать поток воспользуйтесь таймером:

```
QTimer::singleShot(2000, object, SLOT(slot()));
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что программа зависает не отобразив даже первый рисунок

Comment: @kotelliada, попробуйте перед паузой написать `QCoreApplication::processEvents();`

Answer (score 4):

На самом деле, если хочется сделать паузу по-быстрому и по-простому, то лучше использовать не `sleep`, а

> void QTest::qWait ( int ms ) [static]
>
> Ждёт ms миллисекунд. Пока идёт ожидание, события будут обрабатываться и ваш тест продолжает отвечать на события пользовательского интерфейса и сетей связи.

А ещё более правильно использовать, например, `QEventLoop`, из цикла `exec()` которого можно вываливаться по требуемому событию (допустим, разового таймера).